# jQuery - select the second row in a table?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I target the second `<tr>` in a table using jQuery? Do I use `.closest` or `nth-child`?

```
// something like this..
var MyLocation = $('.myclass').closest('tr').after('tr');   // fixed


<table class ='myclass'>
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
   <!-- put some thing here -->
<tr>

</tr>
```

Comment: Also make sure that you use $('.myclass') with the period before the class name instead of $('myclass'). Without the period, you would be looking for an element called <myclass>

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
$('.myclass tr').eq(1)
```

This will grab the second one.

Comment: +1 on this answer because it's by far the fastest. http://jsperf.com/jquery-eq-vs-first-vs-sel-eq-0

Comment: what if I want to find 1 and 2?

Comment: @blackhawk I would make two calls.

Answer (score 49):

Use the nth-child selector. See http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
$('.myclass tr:nth-child(2)')
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `:first` selector in combination with the [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) function:

```
$("TheElementToInsert").insertAfter(".myClass tr:first");
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to add a <tr>, though.
It sounds more like he's trying to get to the existing second <tr>.

Comment: @Zak, I would disagree based on the `<!-- put some thing here -->` after the first `tr` in the OP.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! I did not pay close enough attention to where that was. I read it as being between the <tr> and </tr> tags. My bad!